# divisor count with printing the maximum value

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, prime-factoring

I am new to python and there is a problem with one of my practices that I cant figure out, would appriciate if you could help me.

practice asks me to find the divisors through each 20 inputs with most divisors(count) and print it along with the original number, now the problem is sometimes there is 2 numbers with the same maximum divisors counts (for example  594 and 570 have 16 divisor numbers) and here I have to print the bigger number.

example input :

```
639
883
777
946
843
889
951
789
550
677
708
633
605
878
538
812
570
608
594
619
```

Desired output :

```
594 16
```

my code :

```
`def divisor(x) :
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(1, x+1) :
        if x % i == 0 :
            cnt += 1
    return cnt

div_max = 0
div_val = 0

for j in range(20) :
    x = int(input())
    if divisor(x) > div_max :
        div_max = divisor(x)
        div_val = x
        if div_val < x and divisor(x) == div_max :
                div_val = x
                div_max = divisor(x)

print(div_val, div_max)
```

my output :
570 16

please just advise on my current code, what is the problem and how I can fix it, cheers

Comment: "594 and 570 have 16 prime numbers".
Could you explain ?

Comment: sorry if my english is bad, I meant 594 has 16 divisor and 570 also has 16 divisor, I dont know why I wrote prime numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed a few logic issues to make it work.

First simplify by computing once `divisor(x)` and assign it to the `div` variable.

Changed your condition `if div_val < x and divisor(x) == div_max` to `if div >= div_max`.

And mainly retain the max value : `div_val = max(div_val, x)`.

```py
def divisor(x):
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        if x % i == 0 :
            cnt += 1
    return cnt


div_max = 0
div_val = 0

for j in range(20):
    x = int(input())
    div = divisor(x)
    if div >= div_max:
        div_val = max(div_val, x)
        div_max = div

print(div_val, div_max)
```

Comment: thanks for your code, but the practice wants me write the number with its own divisor counts, for example for the inputs I gave it in the question, the answer should be:
`594 16`

so it means  594 is the maximum value with maximum number of divisors.
I know I may explained bad in my question.

Comment: just changed `div_val = max(div_val, x)` to `div_val = x` and it all went good, thanks.